# Older kitten (4 months) bullying younger kitten (2 months)

Tags: cats, aggression

I had a 4 months old black cat (female) named Friday. Bold and adaptable. Long-ish haired unknown breed.

I just got a 2 months old Siamese kitten. Kind of skittish, male.

The older kitten is bullying the younger one. Chasing her around, staring at her, hits her with the paw (no blood) etc. Nothing serious happened yet, and I don't expect to happen. Younger cat is scared all the time, doesn't eat much, didn't see her in the litter.

How should I handle this? I want to keep both kittens.